# Why does the chr function give unexpected output?

Tags: php, perl

In Perl `print chr(0x263a);` will print a perfect smiley - `☺`.

In PHP `print chr(0x263a);` will print a colon `:`.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: "Return" where using what font?

Comment: i dont understand your question :/

Comment: extending what Mat said - a ascii char is a byte so it does 0x263a&&0xFF=0x3a which gives `:` (ASCII). if you converted it from hex (not as a single char) it would give you `&:` which is the ascii representation of that unicode

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Perl's chr function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html) returns the character represented by that number in either ascii or unicode.

> Returns the character represented by that NUMBER in the character set. For example, chr(65) is "A" in either ASCII or Unicode, and chr(0x263a) is a Unicode smiley face.

[PHP's chr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) is just for ascii.

> Returns a one-character string containing the character specified by ascii.

The reason PHP is printing a colon is because an ascii value is between 0 and 255...

```
0x263a % 256 = 58
```

58 in ascii is a colon.

Answer (score 7):

Read the [chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) documentation page. `chr` only works on ASCII values in `php`.

Look down that page, there are Unicode conversion helpers down in there (look for `uchr` for example).